# Как передать значение

Tags: android-sdk, android, java, android-studio

В MainActivity есть ExpandableListView, как передать значение при нажатиии на лист из MainActivity  в ImageAdapter? Если можно с примерами или ссылками что покурить

Answer (score 1):

у ExpandableListView есть методы [setOnChildClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#setOnChildClickListener(android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener)) и [setOnGroupClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#setOnGroupClickListener(android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener)). С их помощью и можно выполнить какой-либо код при нажатии на элемент списка.

Насколько я знаю, в Android нету класса ImageAdapter. Поэтому вы его либо сами создали, либо где-то взяли. А значит никто вам не расскажет, как туда что-либо передать, потому что никто не знает, что это за класс. Вам никто не поможет, пока вы не выложите сюда его код, и не объясните, что в вашем понимании значит "передать в него значение"